# How to list current elements of an array in Javascript

Tags: javascript

How do I iterate through an array and return the position of each element? I want to write a function that returns each of the elements with their position.

Example:

```
const fruit = ['Orange', 'Banana', 'Apple']
```

Return "My favourite fruit are : 1. Orange, 2. Banana, 3. Apple"

```
function currentLine(array) {
  if (array.length === 0) {
    return `There is no one on line`
  } else {
    return `The line is currently: 1. ${array[0]}, 2. ${array[1]}`
  }
}
```

Comment: `['one', 'two', 'three'].forEach((f, ix) => console.log(``${ix + 1}. ${f}``))`

Answer (score 2):

This will return the desired string for the non-empty case:

```
return array.map((fruit, index) => `${index + 1}. ${fruit}`).join(', ');
```

The [`.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) function call passes the fruit name and its index in turn, returning an entry per fruit, which are then turned into a comma separate list with the call to `.join`.

Comment: Thanks @Alnitak What is the parameter index going to take as an argument?

Comment: @YonasTekeste the `.map` function always passes the current element's index as the second parameter to the callback function.

Answer (score 1):

Fancier ways exist, but for the novice level, this would normally be handled with a for loop.

```
var outputString = "My favourite fruit is: ";
for(var i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
    //add the i + 1 and array[i] to output string concatenation +
}
return outputString;
```

One tricky thing is that the array starts at 0, but you probably don't want your output list to be 0. Orange... so that's why it's i + 1 and not just i.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `array.reduce`:

```js
const fruit = ['Orange', 'Banana', 'Apple'];

const requiredString = fruit.reduce(
  (acc, curr, index) => {
    return `${acc} ${index+1} ${curr}, `;
  }, 'The line is currently:' // this is the default value of the acc
)

console.log(requiredString);
```

This way, you would not need to `join` after a `map`

Comment: An array join is more efficient than a sequence of individual concatentions and/or interpolations.

Comment: `reduce` is the wrong method here. It leaves a dangling `,` in all cases. You want `map`/`join`, which only inserts the delimiter *between* elements. For a `reduce` solution to work, you would have to use the third "current index" argument to your reducer function to figure out whether to add a delimiter, and at that point you've definitely overcomplicated the solution.

Comment: I believe we can simply remove the trailing `,` after the reduce function is complete

Comment: Thanks, Shubham. What if I want to achieve this with simple for loop?

Comment: Yonas, you could try this:
https://codepen.io/Shubham2212/pen/ZPPVpg?editors=1111

Comment: Thank you so much Shubham. I need alittle more explanation on this. 

let result = fruit.length ? 'The line is currently:' : 'There is no one on line';

I am not sure how this is working?

Comment: Happy to help :)
So `let result = fruit.length ? 'The line is currently:' : 'There is no one on line';`
is a ternary statement. if the `fruit` array is empty, then fruit.length will be 0 and hence false-y. so, the part to the right of the `:` will be executed.
If the `fruit` array has one or more elements, fruit.length > 1 and hence truthy. So, the part to the left of the `:` will be executed.

Comment: Dear Shubham. I am new to javascript and this is a little advanced for me. Is there a way I can write is in a simple way for now. Bellow is how I am trying to write but I am not getting the solution  I am looking for. Please check. 

function currentLine(array) {
let result = array.length;
if (array.length === 0) {
 return `There is no one in line.`
} else {
 for(let i=0; i<array.length; i++) 
 result = ${i + 1}, ${array[i]}`
}

return result;
}

Answer (score -1):

Not entirely sure what it is you are looking to return here, but perhaps the .indexOf method of the Array object would help?

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf

For example:

```
["a","b","c"].indexOf("a");
// returns a result of 0, as in "a" is in position 0
```

Comment: The OP edited their question to provide a little clarity after I had written the above.

Comment: Thanks @Ric This is my problem to solve. "Build a function current that accepts the current line of people and returns the current line as a string; for example, if 'theCurrentLine' is currently ["John", "Peter"], current(theCurrentLine) would return "The line is currently: 1. John, 2. Peter""

Comment: You could use the indexOf method to do that but as others have provided several valid methods to achieve what you want you might want to just grab one of theirs. One minor note is that if you are supporting older browsers, many of the suggestions given will not work for you as they rely on ES6. If that IS a concern (and it may not be) you might want to check this URL for ES6 support in things like IE11 (the most modern IE for Windows 7)..
https://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/

Comment: Nobody should be using IE11 these days to be fair, I only mention it as I've had cases where I've had to write internal web apps in an environment where they are still on Windows 7 and use IE as their standard browser. It's more common than you'd think (and certainly more common than it *should* be!)

Answer (score -1):

You Can use reduce as shown below

```
['Orange', 'Banana', 'Apple'].reduce((sentence, element, index)=>`${sentence} ${index}.${element}`, 'The line is currently:')
```

To cater for ','. You can do it this way

```
['Orange', 'Banana', 'Apple'].reduce(
(sentence, element, index, wordsArray)=>`${sentence} ${index}.${element}${(index < wordsArray.length-1)?',':''}`, 'The line is currently:')
```

You can look into how reduce works [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) To make it work as you want or refactor it to become more readable

Comment: This outputs `""The line is currently: 0.Orange 1.Banana 2.Apple"` with no `, ` between the elements.

Comment: Edited the answer to cater for ', '